# Why is this composition code not working?

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors

My program shows an error "cannot resolve the symbol 'getThePixels'" (in class `Main`). The code basically creates a `Monitor` class which contains an object of `Resolution` class. I am trying to access `Resolution` class method through monitor object.
The following is the code:

Main:

```
public class Main {
    Resolution resolution = new Resolution(10);
    Monitor monitor = new Monitor(12,13,14,resolution);
    monitor.getThePixels().pix();
}
```

Monitor:

```
public class Monitor {
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private int length;
    Resolution thePixels;

    public Monitor(int height, int width, int length, Resolution thePixels) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
        this.thePixels = thePixels;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public Resolution getThePixels() {
        return thePixels;
    }
}
```

Resolution:

```
public class Resolution {
    private int pixels;

    public Resolution(int pixels) {
        this.pixels = pixels;
    }

    public void pix() {
        System.out.println("resolution is" + pixels);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JeroenHeier It doesn't compile buddy. That's what he said.

Answer (score 5):

You should write your Main class like that.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Resolution resolution = new Resolution(10);
        Monitor monitor = new Monitor(12,13,14,resolution);
        monitor.getThePixels().pix();
    }
}
```

You can't call method on object inside the body of class.

Answer (score 3):

The call to `getThePixels` is fine. Java, however, doesn't allow calling methods in the middle of a class. These type of calls need to be in a method, constructor, anonymous block or assignment.

It seems you meant to call these line from a `main` method:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { // Here!
        Resolution resolution = new Resolution(10);
        Monitor monitor = new Monitor(12,13,14,resolution);
        monitor.getThePixels().pix();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you wrote :

```
public class Main {
    Resolution resolution = new Resolution(10);
    Monitor monitor = new Monitor(12,13,14,resolution);
    monitor.getThePixels().pix();
}
```

this is not gonna be run , because you don't have a `main` method to run it :
i mean :

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

if you rewrite it with `main` method , it works :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Resolution resolution = new Resolution(10);
        Monitor monitor = new Monitor(12,13,14,resolution);
        monitor.getThePixels().pix();
    }
}
```